# Strange Redraw behavior in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, redraw, android-compatibility

I am using android support package v4 and the following layout to show up a scrollable tabbar + corresponding slideable contentviews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <HorizontalScrollView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fillViewport="true"
                            android:scrollbars="none">
            <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

It works well lets say 90% but 10% it just don't redraw the ui. Even the invalidate of the elements doesn't solve the problem. 
Now the strangest part: After locking and relocking the phone, everything shows up like expected and works like a charm.

For example:
I add a new tab + fragment.
- Tab + Fragment are added, all methods on them are called, but the UI is just black. lock+unlock = everything is okay again.

Handling userinput on fragment. (See pic)
[image: Userinput on Fragment]

Notice:
I already tested the invalidation of all elements, it doesn't work.

What else can I do to solve this problems?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a memoryleak on the tabhost.